# Do we know who Driver is reporting to in Killing them Softly?

Tags: plot-explanation, killing-them-softly

Driver is seen talking exclusively with Jackie throughout the movie.  Jackie lets Driver know what needs to happen, and Driver often tells him that 'they aren't going to be happy about that.'

Do we know who Driver is running things by?  I don't believe it's Dillon.

I should add, I've read this book, and that makes it even more clear that it's not Dillon.  Driver is not fazed during the final negotiation when he hears about Dillon's fate.

Answer (score 2):

The same question was being asked by Jackie in their first meeting under the bridge.

> Jackie: Who's running things?
>
> Driver: You've no idea. No decision-makers. I got to take them by the hand and I got to walk them slowly through it like they're retarded children.
>
> Jackie: What is it, a committee?
>
> Driver: Total corporate mentality.
>
> Jackie: Christ's sake.

So my best guess is that the Driver reported to some syndicate, some kind of group of mafia and not some individual.